# Marker validation using transcriptome and genomic sequences derived from a single cell

Tags: human-biology, bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

I conducted a SSR marker analysis using bioinformatic tool on some RNA-seq data of human tissues. Now, my supervisor believed that we have to validate these SSR on a transcriptomic and genomic sequences derived from single cell.

My question is: why I should do validation on sequences from single cell? Thanks for sharing your idea and experience here.

Comment: SSR=simple sequence repeats ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your supervisor wants to see if there is inter-cellular variation in the repeat length and if so, calculate the variation. This may be compared with inter-tissue or inter-individual variation.

Usually when you take a pool of cells for any assay, you would average out the properties of individual cells.

Using sequencing you may actually be able to find the variability in the repeat length if your reads are long enough. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite), the SSRs are 2-5bp long motifs that are repeated 5-50 times. So the max length would be 250bp, sequencing which, is an easy task. So you would be able to know the fraction of the SSRs with a certain length from a pooled sample and obtain a length distribution. This is quite easy if you know the locus of the repeats and use specific primers for sequencing.

However, if you do not know the exact locus of your SSRs and you are doing random RNA/DNA fragmentation and total RNA/DNAseq, then you may not be able to do that so easily.

In any case I think that it is easier to determine the locus and do targeted sequencing in pooled sample, than doing single-cell RNAseq (At least if the objective is to obtain repeat length distribution).